# Using .this to ToggleClass when another element is clicked

Tags: jquery, this

I am trying to do this rollover thing that works great but for some reason one line of animation (`.info` will not add the `info-up` class) wont trigger. It either works for every iteration of the class on the screen or when I used this, it doesn't work individually.

```js
$(".full-bio").hide();

$(".inner-2").each(function(){
  $(this).hover(function(){
    $(".info",this).toggleClass("info-up");
    $(this).toggleClass("move-up");
    $(".full-bio", this).fadeToggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
}

#jar {
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/2984366/V3_kiip_December2017/Images/icon-flame.svg?t=1532539767047");
  background-position: 100% center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 0deg, rgb(5,210,220) 0%, rgb(0,92,198) 100%);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 0deg, rgb(5,210,220) 0%, rgb(0,92,198) 100%);
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #05d2dc 0%, #005cc6 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.info-up {
  height: 99%;
  transform: none;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height:30%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.inner-2 {
  width: auto;
  height:100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -77%;
  transition: all 1s;
  padding: 1em;
}

.move-up {
  transform: translateY(-70%);
}

.full-bio {
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="jar">
      <div class="blue">IMG</div>
      <div class="info">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="inner">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="inner-2">
          <h2>Header</h2>
          <h3>Sub Title</h3>
            <p class="full-bio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus faucibus, dui ut auctor ultricies, mauris tellus hendrerit urna, sit amet eleifend tellus lectus et lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce a diam ut tortor rhoncus semper. Cras ultrices sollicitudin ornare. Integer et dui sed lacus convallis suscipit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="jar">
      <div class="blue">IMG</div>
      <div class="info">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="inner">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="inner-2">
          <h2>Header</h2>
          <h3>Sub Title</h3>
            <p class="full-bio">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus faucibus, dui ut auctor ultricies, mauris tellus hendrerit urna, sit amet eleifend tellus lectus et lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce a diam ut tortor rhoncus semper. Cras ultrices sollicitudin ornare. Integer et dui sed lacus convallis suscipit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .siblings() to select sibling elements. Here .info class is sibling of .inner-2.

Just change your code to this.

```
$(".inner-2").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".info").toggleClass("info-up");
        $(this).toggleClass("move-up");
        $(".full-bio", this).fadeToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/39ksah65/

Comment: You should go with Jane's solution because like she said, .each is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason 's answer should work, but I just want to point out that you don't actually need the `.each` loop, and your code will work better if you omit it:

```
$('.inner-2').hover(function(){ //this sets an event listener for the "hover" event for all 
                                //elements with a class="inner-2"

    $(this).siblings(".info").toggleClass("info-up");
    $(this).toggleClass("move-up");
    $(".full-bio", this).fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

You only need to use the `.each` when you are changing an element *without* using an event listener (on mouseclick, hover, etc.), or if you need to trigger the loop when an event listener triggers on a different element.

For example, lets say you want to hide all elements with `class="foo"` when a user pushes a button with an `id="bar"`:

```
$('#bar').on('click', function() { // when button is pressed

  $('.foo').each(function() {
    $(this).hide(); //hide all elements with class="foo"
  });
```

Hope this helps!
    });